# conditioned mean

Tags: conditional-expectation

I have a exercise, which is given as
Let the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have $f(x,y)=1$, where $-x<y<x$ and $0<x<1$. I need to show that the $E(X|y)$ is not linear, where I was told that the limits of $X$ would be $|y|<x<1$, but I cannot figure out, why?

Can someone help me?

Comment: It is not clear how you define $f$ for $|y|\ge x$ and what is the range of $X$, $Y$.

Comment: I suggest to replace every occurrence of E(X|y) (which corresponds to nothing) by E(X|Y=y).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that for any given fixed $y$ the range of $x$ is $|y| < x < 1$ is that if
$|y| \geq x$, then either $y$ is positive and $y>x$, or   $y$ is negative and $y < --x$; either of those contradicts $-x<y<x$.  (The $x<1$ part of the condition is more obvious: it is needed to ensure that $0<x<1$.)

Now fix $Y$ at some value $y$.  Then since $f(x,y)$ is constant on the entire $+x$ facing right isosceles triangle, $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(|y|,1)$.  Thus 
$$
E(X|y) = \frac{|y|+1}{2}
$$
That is in fact a linear function of $y$ in the domain $y > 0$ or the domain $y < 0$, but for positive $y$ the slope is positive $\frac{1}{2}$ while for negative $y$ the slope is negative $\frac{1}{2}$.  So the overall function $E(X|y)$ is not linear.